# How to set the images of a Switch in Kivy?

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Hej

I like to customize the On/Off Switch in kivy. For a Button I know how to do it. The kv code looks like this:

```
Button:
    background_normal: 'gfx/offButton.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/onButton.png'
```

Now I whant to know it for the Switch widget. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch does not have properties to control this. Maybe it should, but it also has more behaviour than just on/off since you can drag the slider.

If you just want an active/inactive choice, you could use a CheckBox (which does have background image properties).